# Git - Azure DevOps "error: RPC failed; HTTP 413 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 413"

Tags: git, version-control, azure-devops

I'm trying to push a 240mb commit to azure devops git repository via https and I get this error:
"error: RPC failed; HTTP 413 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 413"

I've read through several other posts, but none of them seem to solve my problem or match what I'm experiencing.

I've tried
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000

and then recommitting, but it doesn't appear to give me more than 150mb of headroom.  (151mb and I get the same error)   I don't want to use SSH.

Azure DevOps has a 5gb commit limit which was working fine before a day or two ago.

**Edit 6/19/2020:**

I'm using 'git push' or the push command via visual studio.  The cmd shows results such as:

```
Enumerating objects: 1086, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1086/1086), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1082/1082), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1084/1084), 231.22 MiB | 7.48 MiB/s, done.
Total 1084 (delta 438), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; HTTP 413 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 413
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

**EDIT: 6/20/2020**

I reinstalled my operating system but it I still have the same problem pushing.

Comment: Are you using the `git push origin master` command? Can you share the details about your steps to reproduce the issue? I tried to push a commit with 300+ mb, but it worked well... Please check the size of your repository and try pushing the commit with another machine in good network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help Lance Li-MSFT.  I tried a new repository and had the same issue, I ended up creating a new organization and a new repository and it checked in ok, so I think I must have hit a ceiling in the overall repository size across the organization.